# Tag Synonym Request: [google-charts] [google-visualization] [google-charts-api] [google-geochart]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

## Executive Summary

I believe the following 4 tags should be consolidated to [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization):

- [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization)
- [google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts)
- [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api)
- [google-geochart](/questions/tagged/google-geochart)

## Reasoning

[google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts) and [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api) are refer to [Google Image Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/image/) which have been deprecated for over a year and have been replaced by the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference?hl=en).

[google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts) and [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api) questions are usually actually asking about [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization). Since there are very few users with enough reputation to identify the differences between the two and retag properly, the tags are currently a giant mess and aren't getting any better as time goes on.

All four of these topics have incredibly similar types of questions in them, and there are a lot of cross-tags. There are very few answerers who frequent one of these tags, but not the other three, but there are many people asking questions in one tag who may not be aware of the others. None of these tags get much traffic in general, meaning it is hard for the regulars to actually manage the tags due to insufficient reputation.

[google-geochart](/questions/tagged/google-geochart) is a subset of [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization), but there is no tag for 'google-barchart' or 'google-histogram' which are equivalent (and further would need to be distinguished from google-visualization-barchart and google-charts-barchart due to the current charts/visualization split).

So to make things simple, due to the lack of traffic, just make them all synonyms of each other with [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization) as the main tag, so that the already low traffic at least gets aggregated and seen by more people.

## Overlap

*Note: below numbers are from May, not much has changed since then*

[google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts) has 1,168 questions

- 235 (20%) are tagged [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api)
- 107 (9%) are tagged [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization)

[google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization) has 579 questions

- 107 (18%) are tagged [google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts)
- 27 (5%) are tagged [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api)
- 10 (2%) are tagged [google-geocharts](/questions/tagged/google-geocharts)

[google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api) has 371 questions

- 235 (63%) are tagged [google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts)
- 27 (7%) are tagged [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization)

[google-geochart](/questions/tagged/google-geochart) has 43 questions

- 10 (23%) are tagged [google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts)
- 10 (23%) are tagged [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization)
- 3 (7%) are tagged [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api)

## Last 30 Days of Activity

- 10 questions [google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts)
- 3 questions [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization)
- 7 questions [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api)
- 1 question [google-geochart](/questions/tagged/google-geochart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and merged [google-charts](/questions/tagged/google-charts) into [google-visualization](/questions/tagged/google-visualization) and created a synonym, since my exploration into the subject shows that at least half of those question *were* actually Google Visualization questions (and a synonym of those two required a merge).

I've also added [google-charts-api](/questions/tagged/google-charts-api) and [google-geochart](/questions/tagged/google-geochart) as synonyms, as requested, but did not perform merges on those two.

Comment: Thank you animuson! You have made my day. Now everything is in one magical place and there will be less confusion.

Comment: bonus points for independent exploration of the subject, instead of just blindly trusting us Meta folk