# Award a bounty, break a question

Tags: bug, bounties, 500-server-error

I just started a bounty [to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181099/tag-synonym-request-google-charts-google-visualization-google-charts-api).

Upon starting it, I was lead to the ["Oops! Something bad happened" page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/181099/tag-synonym-request-google-charts-google-visualization-google-charts-api). No big deal. Let's go back and see if it took....what? I can't visit it any more?

It seems the bounty itself took (the question even appeared on the front page), but the question itself somehow broke. Perhaps it's a temporary glitch, but I've confirmed in chat that I'm not the only one with the problem. Did the bounty break something?

**Update:**

So it seems to work again. Yet there are two "notice added" events in the post's revision history, as noted by Jeremy Banks. Seems strange.

**Update 2:**

Hey, at least the system is consistent. The notice has been [removed twice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/181099/revisions) now as well. :)

Comment: As I reached reading "*Oops! Something Bad Happened!*", a lizard dropped on my table. :|

Comment: ...and suddenly it works.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason the "Notice added" event appears twice in [the post's revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/181099/revisions).

Comment: Weird. Something hit the fan...

Comment: Looks like [meta-tag:status-norepro] to me, unless you remember doing anything special before it happened?

Comment: It's Ooopsing for me right now...

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Besides my usual interpretive dance of the bounty process, nope. Nothing special.

Comment: Let's hope those two notices will be enough to debug and hunt down the bug then... :)

Comment: One bounty, two post notices... probably some temporary database hiccup caused that, good thing the code is smart enough to not crash as a result!